# No Operating system - how to install ubuntu to a flash drive

Tags: boot

My laptop does not have an operating system because my daughter removed it.
Can I install Ubuntu on to a flash drive?

Actully i have a windows 7 disc but after downloading that, the laptop asks for drivers to be installed but I do not have such a disc for the drivers. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AU! Your question is a bit unclear in one point: Do you want to install Ubuntu *from* a thumb drive or *onto* a thumb drive? Both are possible and you mention both in your question. Question about the installation process of Windows are [off topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: At first I wanted to download ubuntu to my thumb drive and then install from the thumb drive. Now I have a R/W disc and is trying to install ubuntu from the disc after downloading ubuntu onto the disc. Still unable to do it. Will try what Miguel suggested.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install ubuntu from a thumb drive if you have access to some other working computer.

Download the ubuntu iso file, download the linux iso-to-usb writer program, write on usb drive, boot your computer without OS with that usb drive.

Two of the good programs to write Linux iso-to-usb are:
http://unetbootin.github.io/
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install Ubuntu on to a flash drive. 32gb flash or above recommend. First burn Ubuntu install iso on a dvd, once complete boot computer with dvd select "try ubuntu". Next dowload gparted in software center on Ubuntu, partition flash drive in gparted. Once completed click on the install ubutu linknon desktop and follow prompts it should select the flash drive if you partitioned it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here are the instructions to install ubuntu on your computer as your operating system and start using this amazing OS.
*First you need to do this on another computer (I used a windows computer and this is what I did).*

**You will need:**

- A USB 3.0 with enough memory to allocate the image in it (about 8G)
- A laptop hard drive enclosure

**Steps:**

1. download the Universal-USB-installer http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
2. download the desktop 'disk image file' to a folder on the windows pc.
3. insert the flash drive in your computer and open up the Universal-USB-Installer and agree with the terms.
4. Select the linux system you will upload to the flash drive, browse and select the image, select the usb flash drive and check on formatting the drive.
5. Click create and this will take a few minutes. When 'done' click close.
6. restart your computer to reboot on your flash drive (if you don't know how to do this, ask me, or search the web).
7. once the image is booted, click on install the image and connect your enclosure with your laptops hard drive in it and follow the step to install it in your hard drive.